# Enable HTML5 AppCache using javascript?

Tags: html

```
<html manifest="example.appcache">
```

Can you add the **manifest="example.appcache"** part using javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically Trigger HTML5 Cache Manifest file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548342/dynamically-trigger-html5-cache-manifest-file)

Answer (score 0):

No you can't because the html file is already sent to the server so further changes to manifest attribute won't make the browser react to it.
I tried it with :

```
document.documentElement.manifest = "site.manifest";
```

And loading the pages with and without internet, in the seconde case it says "connection error" obviously